# Angular directive unit testing: $templateCache or $httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I'm testing directives that use the `templateUrl` property, and was wondering what the best way is to compile the templates.  Is is better to use `$templateCache` or `$httpBackend`?  I am guessing it's better to use `$templateCache` since I think this is the use case it was made for, but I've seen it done both ways.  Although I haven't got the `$httpBackend` method fully functional yet.

**NOTE**: the second test is for the rewrite of the original project.  The first test is from the original project.

The `$templateCache` way:

```
describe('buttonToggle', function() {
    var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('src/app/partials/buttonToggle/buttonToggle.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, _$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        template = $templateCache.get('src/app/partials/buttonToggle/buttonToggle.html');
        $templateCache.put('src/app/partials/buttonToggle/buttonToggle.html', template);

        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it('should have an on/off switch', function() {
        var buttonElement = angular.element('<button-toggle></button-toggle>');
        var element = $compile(buttonElement)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(element.text()).toContain('ON');
        expect(element.text()).toContain('OFF');
    });
});
```

My nonworking implementation of `$httpBackend`:

```
describe('The buttonToggle directive', function() {

    var $compile,
        $scope,
        $httpBackend,
        btElement,
        btElementPath = 'client/modules/buttonToggle/buttonToggle.html',
        btElementFileName = 'buttonToggle.html';

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.whenGET(btElementPath).respond(200);
        $httpBackend.expectGET(btElementFileName).respond(200);
        btElement = $compile('<button-toggle></button-toggle>')($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should be defined', function() {
        expect(btElement.html()).toContain('btn');
    });
});
```

Also, any ideas on how to get the latter test to work?  I don't think I setup the `whenGET` correctly since the error I am getting from my assertion states that the compiled element is empty.

Comment: Did you get it working?I have the exact same problem.Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually found a short answer from the Angular docs.  If anyone else has good knowledge on this subject, then please feel free to answer, but this is what I found:

> If your directive uses templateUrl, consider using karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor to pre-compile HTML templates and thus avoid having to load them over HTTP during test execution. Otherwise you may run into issues if the test directory hierarchy differs from the application's.